# MS Access get specific field of a record

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm really new to MS Access and got stuck a little problem which looks like i can't solve it.
Following I have a little example which makes it easier to explain.

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

As you can see I have a little calendar. Very easy and simple. I do a lookup on my **tblCalendarMonths** and on my **tblCalendarYears**. The field **calDisplay** is a calculated field an should put the Month and the Year together. In 'Picture 2' you can see how I tried it. In 'Picture 1' you can see what happens.

All I get is are the IDs of the selected Month and Year. What do I need to do,
to see under Display: "June 2014"

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you want to have the date separated like that in your table? If not you can use the DatePart Function to return the year and month as you desire.

```
DatePart("yyyy", [CalDate]) & " " & MonthName(DatePart("m", [CalDate]))
```